# Mailcatcher gem and Linux Virtual Machine

Tags: rubygems, virtual-machine, vagrant

I have installed the Mailcatcher gem (http://mailcatcher.me/) on my VM managed by Vagrant. And in the Vagrantfile I have set up the forwarding port:

```rb
config.vm.forward_port 1080, 1080
```

I ssh to the guest, run the Mailcatcher on the guest, but when I go to: 127.0.0.1:1080 on my host, I don't see the Mailcather interface. All I get is:

```
No data received.Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data ...
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

--Solution---
see the thread here:
https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher/issues/89

Comment: can you try forwarding it to any port greater than 1080 . May be 1081.

Comment: Actually, I did `mailcatcher --ip=0.0.0.0` on the guest and could access it on 1080 on the host. But I had to kill the mailcatcher process before doing anything. Here is the link to the conversation I had with the developer of the gem.  https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher/issues/89